# uncertain orthogonality of discrete Fourier transform on the ring of integers modulo some number

Tags: ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

**Update**: I corresponded with one of the authors of CLRS, and he confirmed that the problem indeed should say "$n$ is a power of two", not "$n$ is even".

Original question:

The third edition of [CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) Exercise 30.2-6 claims that for any positive even $n$ and positive integer $t$, a discrete Fourier transform can be defined on the ring of integers modulo $m = 2^{tn/2} + 1$, using $w = 2^t$ as the principle $n$th root of unity.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform_(general)#Definition) seems to say that if $w$ is a principal $n$th root of unity, then for $1 \leq k < n$, we must have

$$
T_k = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} w^{jk} = 0 \mod m
$$

However, choosing $n = 6$ and $t = 3$, we have $m = 513$ and $w = 8$, and it's easy to see that $T_2 = 114 \mod m$. Isn't this supposed to be zero? If yes, where have I gone wrong above?

Comment: I did some more testing: the claim made by CLRS seems to only work when $n$ itself is a power of 2, and _not_ in general when $n$ is even.

Comment: No wikipedia is saying that if we have $T_k =0\bmod m$ for each $k\ne 0\bmod n$ then we can use $w$ in a NTT, and that if $m$ is prime  then the condition is satisfied whenever $w$ has order $n$.

Comment: what do you mean "$w$ has order $n$"? What's "order" in this context"?

Comment: The least $n$ such that $w^n=1\bmod m$

Comment: I'm saying that CLRS said $w^t$ is an principal nth root of unity, and if I combine that with wikipedia saying that any principal nth root of unity must have $T_k = 0$, I get contradicting results for the case $n=6, t=3$. I think what happened here is that CLRS had a typo. It's not sufficient for $n$ to merely be even: for example if $n=6$ then $w^t$ is _not_ a principal nth root. Rather, $n$ must be a power of 2 (at least that's what I'm finding empirically).

Comment: in other words, the specific part in wikipedia I'm referring to is when it says "if $\alpha$ is a principal nth root of 1, then $T_k = 0$". I'm not talking about any of the parts like NTT afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any $m$ and $w\in \Bbb{Z/mZ}^\times$ of order $n$, the necessary and sufficient condition for $T_0 \in \Bbb{Z/mZ}^\times$ and $T_1=\ldots=T_{n-1}=0$ is that $\gcd(n,m)=1$ and for each $k\ne 0\bmod n, w^k-1$ is a unit ie. for each prime $p| m$,  $w\bmod p$ has order $n$.

- If $\gcd(n,m)\ne 1$ then $T_0$ is not a unit.
- If each $w^k-1$ is a unit then $w^{nk}-1=0$ implies $T_k=\frac{w^{kn}-1}{w^k-1}=0$.
- If $w^k-1$ is not a unit then $w^k=1\bmod p$ for some $p|m$ thus $T_k = n\ne 0 \bmod p$
- If for each prime $p| m$, $w\bmod p$ has order $n$ then each $w^k-1$ is a unit.
- If for some prime $p| m$, $w\bmod p$ has order $k<n$ then $w^k-1$ is not a unit.

It is not obvious at all for which $n,t$ the condition is satisfied with $m=2^{nt/2}+1, w=2^t$ (except when $n$ is a power of $2$, see comment below)

Comment: do you know why the condition seems to be satisfied when $n > 1$ is a power of 2, and $t$ any positive integer?

Comment: Yes, for $p| 2^{2^{k-1} t}+1$ then $(2^t)^{2^k}=1\bmod p$ means that $2^t\bmod p$ has order $2^l$ with $l\le k$, if $l< k$ then $(2^t)^{2^{k-1}}=1\bmod p$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes it implies that each $w^k-1\bmod m$ is a unit so $w^n-1=0$ gives $w^{nk}-1=0$ thus $T_k=\frac{w^{kn}-1}{w^k-1}=0$

Answer (score 0):

There is almost certainly an error in the CLRS claim, since $n$ being even is not sufficient, as demonstrated by the $n = 6$ counterexample.

On the other hand, $n$ being a power of two *is* sufficient, though it is still unclear to me whether it's necessary.

**Proof** (M. Pinson, private communication):

When $n = 2^\ell$, we have

$$
T_k = \frac{w^{nk} - 1}{w^k-1} = \prod_{J=0}^{\ell-1} \left( w^{2^J k} + 1\right).
$$

Without loss of generality, let $k = 2^R q$ where $q$ is odd. Since $0 < k < n$, we have $0 \leq R < \ell$, and thus we examine the $J = \ell - 1 - R$ factor and see that it becomes $w^{2^{\ell - 1}q} + 1$. Since $x^q + 1$ is always divisible by $x+1$ for any odd $q$ [which can be seen by computing $\sum_{i=0}^{q-1} (-x)^i $], we know that the factor $w^{2^{\ell - 1}q} + 1$ must be divisible by $m = w^{2^{\ell - 1}} + 1$, and we are done.

**Update**: I corresponded with one of the authors of CLRS, and he confirmed that the problem indeed should say "$n$ is a power of two", not "$n$ is even".

**Update 2** In CLRS fourth edition $n$ is now indeed "an exact power of 2" in problem 30.2-6

Answer (score 0):

Let $m$ be a positive integer with the prime factorization $m = p_1^{d_1} p_2^{d_2} \cdots p_k^{d_k}$. A discrete Fourier transform of length $n$ is definable if $n$ divides $\boldsymbol{0}(m) := gcd(p_1 - 1, p_2 - 1, \dots, p_k - 1)$ as shown in [Fast Convolution using fermat number transforms with applications to digital filtering](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1162555).

Additionally, the condition for commutative rings is that the transform length $n$ must be invertible in the ring and there must exist a principal $n$-th root of unity. See [Faster Integer Multiplication](https://epubs.siam.org) or [Integer Multiplication in $O(n log n)$](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2021/193-2/p04). It can be shown, with some effort, for an integer ring $\mathbb{Z}_m$, the existence of a principal $n$-th root of unity with $n$ invertible is equivalent to $n | \boldsymbol{0}(m)$.